# Windowless container for Google App Engine channel API client

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, v8

I would like to write a commandline tool that receives notifications from Google App Engine's Channel API. This seems to be quite straightforward thanks to open JavaScripts VMs such as v8 and js. One problem with this approach, though, is that these VMs do not provide standard js objects such as `window` and `document`, which the channel API references. Running such code therefore gives you `window/document/.. not found` errors.

There seem to be two ways of circumventing this obstacle:

1. To write a lightweight header in javascript to emulate the behavior of the required objects.
2. To edit Google's javascript (/_ah/channel/jsapi) and eliminate references to such objects.

Does anyone know if there are existing implementations of these approaches, or know of a better idea? Furthermore, is there a clean, uncompressed version of the channel API client side javascript code available somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't edit the script used by /_ah/channel/jsapi -- it's only used when the channel is running against the dev app server. When running in production, that script redirects to https://talkgadget.google.com/talkgadget/channel.js

So you're left with emulating the required objects, or just using a hidden browser window. I would opt for the latter, since I think emulating all the DOM calls is going to get very difficult very quickly.

Comment: Yes, that's what I settled on. I am now using Phantomjs (http://phantomjs.org), which wraps Webkit in a way that can be linked as a library. Another option would have been to use the XMPP API with a single user, instead of using Channels.

Comment: The downside to the XMPP API is that it would require the user to have a gmail or other XMPP account. An extra complication is that I'm not sure if newer gmail accounts (that presumably have Hangouts enabled) will federate with App Engine XMPP anymore. I haven't researched what's happened with App Engine XMPP <-> gmail chat federation since Hangouts shipped.

Comment: I believe that federation doesn't work anymore. Isn't it the case that you can use multiple jids with a single user? Something like x@y.com/0, x@y.com/1 etc. I don't need presence, only messaging.

Comment: Yep, XMPP supports a notion of resources to send messages to particular clients (so foo@bar.com/adium wouldn't get messages sent to foo@bar.com/application)